# uploading multiple files to slack with curl

Tags: curl, slack-api

I'm using the following command to upload files to slack:

`curl https://slack.com/api/files.upload -F token="xoxb-***-***-***" -F channels="channel_name" -F title="photo" -F filename="photo" -F file=@"photo.JPG"`

How can I update the command to upload all files in the folder?

I tried the command below and it did not work.

`curl https://slack.com/api/files.upload -F token="xoxb-***-***-***" -F channels="channel_name" -F title="photo" -F filename="photo" -F file=@"*.JPG"`

Comment: I know this question is 2 years old, but does this have a solution now? I'm running into the same issue

Answer (score 0):

```
curl -F file=path_to_file -F channels=CHANNEL_ID -H "Authorization: Bearer xoxb-****" https://slack.com/api/files.upload filename="photo"
```

The ChannelId is not the channel name, you can see the channel id on right click on the channel click see details and should start like this "C*******"

And check token authorization SCOPES